# Sending multiple SMS with different content to different numbers

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I'm working on a school project. What I want to do is to send the result of each student to their phone number from the school's website. All the data are fetched from a mysql table with four columns: id, name, number, message. Initially, I tried sending the message through an html form which involves sending the messages manually one by one to each student with this code:

```
$sendto = $_POST['number'];   /* student number html form */  
$message = $_POST['content'];  /* message from html form */
$url = "http://www.smsgateway.com?"  
            . "&email=name@mail.com"  
            . "&pwd=password"  
            . "&message=" . UrlEncode($message) 
            . "&sendto=" . UrlEncode($sendto);   

$f = @fopen($url, "r")
```

It worked. But I want to send the messages once. I already have all the data in a mysql table. From the little research I did, curl was recommended. But I don't how I can use curl to send the multiple result at once. Please how can I do this or is there any better method I can use?

Comment: I don't know smsgateway but some gateways accept multiple numbers separated by ; or another separator. Have you already tried this?

Comment: The gateway I'm using also accepts that, but I'm not sending the same message to all the students. I'm sending a students' unique result to his number

Comment: Then I don't understand what you exactly want to. What do you mean by "But I want to send the messages once"? Maybe you could provide some example.

Comment: loop the contacts\number seend one sms each

Comment: That is, just by click a button, and then, the script will fetch all the messages(results) and send to the corresponding numbers on the mysql table